# How to limit the recursive in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, find, cakephp-2.0, limit, recursive-query

I'm working on a movie website project. I need to limit 5 reviews per movie page.

```
$this->Movie->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('Movie.url' => $req ), // URL to fetch the required page
    'recursive' => 1
));
```

Using the above code I'm getting 1 movie details and all(almost 20 for now) the reviews related to that movie. So how can I limit the reviews to 5 ?

Comment: ofcourse, I will accept if it works for me.
I simply can't accept the one which didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think no one knows how to solve, I found the some way that I can solve it temporarily.
Please someone tell me about the best practice.

```
$movie = $this->Movie->find('first', array(
     'conditions' => array('Movie.url' => $req ),
 'recursive' => 0
));
$this->loadModel('MovieReview');
$movieReview = $this->MovieReview->find('all',array(
    'conditions' => array('MovieReview.movie_id' => $movie['Movie']['id'] ),
    'limit' => 5,
    'recursive' => -1
));
$movie['MovieReview'] = $movieReview;
```

If someone needs to answer this, pls answer the best practice.

Comment: There is no best practice because there is no way to limit the results from associated models running only one query. You have to run a second query or run a complex/raw SQL query to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$this->Movie->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('Movie.url' => $req ), // URL to fetch the required page
    'limit'=>5,
    'recursive' => -1
));
```

Comment: No, This will not work, Coz I don't have any review ID in the Movie model. Pls check my own answer. I fixed it. But I need best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try on associations , set limit option

```
     /**
     * hasMany associations
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $hasMany = array(
        'MovieReview' => array(
            'className' => 'MovieReview',
            'foreignKey' => 'movie_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '25',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Movie->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('Movie.url' => $req ), // URL to fetch the required page
    'contain' => array('MovieReview' => array('limit' => 5))
));
```

With this, you'll get only 5 MovieReview for each Movie returned

*Sorry for my english*

Comment: Even if it could be the right answer, please don't hesitate to add some text to explain what code does.